# Working of useEffect hook in react.js. Problem in dependency array part of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have little confusion on how use effect works.

```
 const recordMouse = e => {
      setX(e.clientX)
      setY(e.clientY)
 }
 useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove',recordmouse)  
 },[])
```

When we provide an empty dependency array the useEffect run on first render, if I'm not wrong, but here I found that I was getting every mouse position.
Can somebody explain what's happening.

Comment: You're subscribing to an event only once, on the first render, but then the event will fire on every mouse move. What are you trying to do?

Comment: *"here I found that I was getting every mouse position"* - where? how are you using it?

Comment: I was displaying the mouse coordinates. My doubt is useEffect was rendering only once but event was fired every time mouse was moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `mouseover` event binding, but the callback（`recordMouse`） is executed every time the `mouseover` is triggered.

It has nothing to do with `useEffect`, you can try it with vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
  const [x, setX] = useState();
  const [y, setY] = useState();

  const recordMouse = e => {
      setX(e.clientX)
      setY(e.clientY)
 }

 return (
   <div onMouseMove={recordMouse}>
     content
   </div>
 )
```